# Assigning current array index to a variable in order to increment it?

Tags: java, arrays, textarea, textfield

I have an array of messages which are called upon to display in a textfield. I would like to assign the array index i.e. [0] to a variable so that when the person enters the correct text I can get the current array index and increment it to the next one to be able to print out. How can I do this?

I have these methods:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String text = commandInput.getText();
    messageDisplay.append("\n \n" + text + "\n \n");
    commandInput.selectAll();

}

public String getCurrentLevel() {
    return currentLevel;
}
```

After commandInput.selectAll(); I would like to do getCurrentLevel() + 1 to get the next element in the array to append.

Here is the array class it is pulling from:

```
package com.game.main;

public class Message {

    public String[] messageArray;

    public Message() {
        messageArray = new String[50];
        messageArray[0] = "Welcome. ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `int myInt = Integer.parseInt(getCurrentLevel()) + 1;` Then convert it to String again (Using `String#valueOf()` for example)

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for, but subsequent calls to getNextMessage() will return the next message in the array. Call it too many times and it will go out of bounds etc. This of course assumes you are not recreating the class  between calls, if so, you need to make the indx static.

An alternative way to do this using an ArrayList instead of an array:

```
//using an ArrayList<String>
public class Message {

    private int indx = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> messages;

public Message() {
    messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    messages.add("Welcome. ");     
}

public String getNextMessage(){
    String s = messages.get(indx);
    indx++;
    return s;
}
```

---

```
// using an array
public class Message {

    private int indx = 0;
    private String[] messageArray;

public Message() {
    messageArray = new String[50];
    messageArray[0] = "Welcome. ";     
}

public String getNextMessage(){
    String s = messageArray[indx];
    indx++;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Do i need both public and private String[]'s especially with the same name? I get an error with that. Plus in the getNextMesage I get an error with i too.

Comment: oops, just a second, did not notice the public one. It would be better to keep the private string array, since you dont want to expose the internal workings of a class outside. It is fixed now

Comment: Thought as much. Still have the "i" not being resolved to a variable. Should I create it or should the array itself pick up on that?

Comment: ah sorry, the i inside the array should be indx. fixed yet again. if you are using and IDE like eclipse these things should be fairly quick to see and fix :)

Comment: i should consider using a List instead of an array.

Comment: Yeah, I would prefer to use an Arraylist instead of an array as well.

Comment: How would I do "getMessageArray" on an array list?